# Getting attachments to work with AppleScript for Mail

Tags: macos, email, pdf, applescript, attachment

I am working with Mac OSX 10.12.6 and have built an AppleScript to create an email and then attach a PDF and a jpeg file. When I run the script i get an error when trying to attach the pdf and jpeg files.

`Mail got an error: Can’t make {file name:"MacintoshHD:Users:peteradam:PPAttachments:EmailFolder:Quote_15018_301017.pdf", file size:200339} into type properties of attachment.`

The error message is repeated for the jpeg with the file name changed.

I have also tried setting `theSignature` and `theAttachment1` as aliases to no avail.

The script is as follows:

```
set TheRecipient to "name"
set theAddress to "me@me.com"
set theSubject to "Expoprint  "
set theContent to "When in Doubt DON'T"
set theSender to "Me <me@me.com>"

tell application "Finder" to set theSignature to "MacintoshHD:Users:peteradam:PPAttachments:EmailFolder:ExpoPrint Signature.jpg"
set theSignatureSize to 20530
tell application "Finder" to set theAttachment1 to "MacintoshHD:Users:peteradam:PPAttachments:EmailFolder:Quote_15018_301017.pdf"
set theAttachmentSize1 to 200339

tell application "Mail"
    set theMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:theSubject, content:theContent & return & return, visible:true}
    tell theMessage
        set sender to theSender
        make new to recipient at end of every to recipient with properties {name:TheRecipient, address:theAddress}
        try
            make new attachment with properties {file name:theAttachment1, file size:theAttachmentSize1} at after last paragraph
            set message_Attachment to 0
        on error errmess
            log errmess
            display dialog errmess
            set message_Attachment to 1
        end try
        log "message_attachment =" & message_Attachment
        make new attachment with properties {file name:theSignature, file size:theSignatureSize} at after last paragraph
        delay 1
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem by removing the File Size properties